# Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject:Id

Tags: apex, force.com, quote

I am stuck with a compile time error "Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject:Id"
If the Totalcontracts are greater than 1 then it is failing.
For multiple contracts with different terms I am using the billing term from the primary contract. Suppose there are 3 contracts with terms 3, 6, 12 and you select first two contracts with terms 3, 6 and make the second contract as primary contract.The primary contract is stored in contractId which is in the argument.

Can anyone help me where i am wrong and how to proceed?

```
public static Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c onQuoteStart(Id contractId, Set<Id> contractIdList) {
          Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c quote = new Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c();
          String contractNumbers = '';
          Contract contract = [SELECT  Id,ContractNumber,sfbase__Billing_Term__c FROM contract WHERE Id=:contractId];
          List<Contract> contractList = new List<Contract>();
          List<Contract> fetchedLstOfContracts = new List<Contract>();
          contractList.add(contract);
          Integer totalContracts = contractIdList.size();

          if (totalContracts == 1) {
            contractNumbers = contract.ContractNumber;
          } else{
              fetchedLstOfContracts = [SELECT  Id,Name,ContractNumber FROM Contract WHERE Id in :contractIdList];
              contractList.addAll(fetchedLstOfContracts);
              for(Contract con : contractList) {
                contractNumbers += (con.ContractNumber + ';');
              }
          }

          if (totalContracts == 1 ){
                            system.debug('@@@@Entered SingleContract Loop');
                            system.debug('@@@@BillingTerm:'+contract.sfbase__Billing_Term__c);
                            quote.SfdcContracts_Reduced__c = contract.ContractNumber;
                            quote.SfdcBillingTerm__c = contract.sfbase__Billing_Term__c; 
          }
          else if(totalContracts > 1 ){
                        system.debug('####Entered MultiContract Loop'); 
                        system.debug('####BillingTerm:'+contractId.sfbase__Billing_Term__c);           
                        quote.SfdcContracts_Reduced__c = contractNumbers;
                        quote.SfdcBillingTerm__c = contractId.sfbase__Billing_Term__c; 
          }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
contractId.sfbase__Billing_Term__c
```

You should reference the entire record to pull a specific field value, not reference its Id:

```
contract.sfbase__Billing_Term__c
```